# Tips for limit memory machine performance? IIS application

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

We have WPF client that communicate with the server by web-service.
In the thick installation both client + server + sqlserver are installed on the same machine. The machine has 500M RAM.

I will be great full for tips about:

1. its very difficult to find the bottleneck , because you can use in profiler on such machine without heavy impact on the result. the profiler can cause to page faults due to missing memory and the diagnostic will show irrelevant results.
2. In the task manger i see that the asp process consume 135M this is too much. I tried to understand why it consume so much and i saw area - undefined. is it the asp process itself? does asp process has a big memory overhead? in this architecture (thick) i don't have multiple clients against the server . do you have any memory advice for it?
3. the benchmark results has big variety . i think it because page fault. do you have any advice?

Thank you very much. i am from java world , so i am new to it.

Comment: Too much trouble, instead of that buy some more memory that is cheap. The cost in time to find all that is bigger than the cost of the memory.

Comment: this is for customer that has thousands of this kinds machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and see whats needs the memory. Also check with starts with your server using the [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902)

Now 500M is little memory for a server.

From my experiences the SQL server needs a memory, iis and asp.net needs also memory, but the SQL need more, especial for cache and be fast, and make the indexing and all that. The asp.net is running with out needs of too much memory, but all depends from how you have setup your system, how many pools you have give to asp.net (I believe only one with 500M), how man sites, how many memory you get with your sites and so on.

### More about

If its possible, move the SQL to a better server, and all the rest computers connect to this one. The SQL server needs memory.

Second possible, move the sap.net session from memory to sql server.

Comment: On this architecture the server serve only single client. How can i reduce the asp process overhead?

Comment: @Avihai I have update my question... move to a single sql server and remote connect to it, remove the session state from memory and move it to sql. Use the autoruns to stop un-nessesary programs from run on the server.

Comment: For this customer, who have thousands of station (500M RAM). client + server + sqlexpress run on the same machine. i must deal with this limitation. Thank you. I dont use in session. one client against one server. no use in session.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the memory use of iis can be done by:

Go to the IIS MMC

->  click Application Pools

->  Right-click the pool

->  select Advanced Settings

->  go to the Recycling section, you will see there are two settings:

- Private Memory Limit (KB)  Virtual
- Memory Limit (KB)

When any of these 2 settings are set, if the worker process exceeds the
private or virtual memory quota, IIS will recycle that pool which limits
the memory usage.

You can limit the SQL server memory use in the SQL MMC, go to the database servers properties

Overall I would recommend to split the database and the iis server. 0.5gb is not a lot of memory for a server.